# Unable to register second validating peer with Hyperledger-Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am fairly new to Hyperledger-Fabric, and I was able to set up two separate VMs, one running as a `membersrvc` instance, and the other as a `validating-peer`. I was able to make REST calls to the Validating peer using credentials that I listed in the `membesrvc.yaml` file in the `membersrvc` server. However, when I try to spin up a second `validating-peer` using `peer node start`, I get the following error:

```
    11:28:56.950 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 007 [validator.fabric2] Failed invoking CreateCertficatePair [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.].
    11:28:56.950 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 008 [validator.fabric2] Failed getting enrollment certificate [id=fabric2]: [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.]
    11:28:56.950 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 009 [validator.fabric2] Failed retrieving enrollment data [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.].
    11:28:56.950 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 00a [validator.fabric2] Failed registering node crypto engine [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.].
    11:28:56.950 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 00b [validator.fabric2] Failed registering peer [fabric2]: [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.]
    11:28:56.950 [crypto] Errorf -> ERRO 00c [validator.fabric2] Failed registering [fabric2]: [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.]
    11:28:56.950 [crypto] RegisterValidator -> ERRO 00d Failed registering validator [fabric2] with name [fabric2] [rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.].
    Error: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Identity or token does not match.
```

I am certain that I have the right credentials in my `core.yml` file, and that they are correct in the `membersrvc.yaml` file on the separate `membersrvc` node.

How can I register a new validating peer as a part of a network of validating peers?

Comment: When you mentioned 2 VMs, are you running them on dockers on each of these VMs? Or is it like you are running the executables ( i.e, membersvc on one VM and peer on another VM)? Have you cleaned the var/production dir ( as per fabric setup doc) on the VM where you have member service setup?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to log in with an already used credential for the new validating-peer ?

Make sure the credentials you use have the "validator" role.